# How to rewrite whole subquery logic and use into store procedure and call the flag column "matched" case statement in select clause of store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Database table :

| trade_nbr | date | amount | txn_typ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-12-21 | 1000 | A |
| 1 | 10-12-21 | -500 | B |
| 1 | 10-12-21 | 250 | C |
| 1 | 10-12-21 | 250 | C |
| 2 | 5-12-21 | 2000 | A |
| 2 | 5-12-21 | -500 | B |
| 2 | 5-12-21 | 500 | C |

For each trade number we get A,B, C transaction.

**Requirement**

When same trade number and date with sum of amount for Transaction A matched with same trade number and date with sum of amount of transaction C then return only C records. and it is consider as flag "matched" . If not matched flag as "unmatched"

My query:

```
select 
    trd_nbr, [date], 
    (case when amountforA=amountforB and amountforB=amountforC then 'Matched' else 'Notmatched' end) Matched
from 
    (select 
         trd_nbr, [date],
         sum(case when txn_typ='A' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforA,
         sum(case when txn_typ='B' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforB, 
         sum(case when txn_typ='C' then abs(amount) else 0 end) amountforC
     from 
         table1
     group by 
         trd_nbr, [date]) t
where
    amountforA > 0 and amountforB > 0 and amountforC > 0
```

Output:

| trd_nbr | date | Amount | Matched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-05 | 4000 | NM |
| 2 | 2021-08-12 | 5000 | NM |

How to include this sub query logic  into store procedure and call flag column in the select clause of the store procedure.

Stored procedure code:

```
create proc ....
begin 
    select 
        column1,
        column2,
        **our_flag** column 
    from 
        (select column1..
         from table 1
         where ...
         union all
         select column1 
         from table 2
         where ...)

end;
```

How to include "our_flag--"Matched" column  in select clause of this stored procedure by including subquery logic also in procedure.

Output:

```
                    |Column1    |"Matched"     |
                    |------   : | :---------   | 
                    |   trade1  |     NM       |  
                    |   trade2  |      M       |
```

Comment: What do you mean, "how to include"? No differently to any other column; include/define it in your `SELECT`.

Comment: I am not getting it. I want to include whole subquery logic into store procedure and call the flag column "matched" case statement in select clause of store procedure.

Comment: I don't follow that sentence at all I am afraid. you don't "call" a subquery, you define it in the query. If you want a parametrised version then you would want to make an inline table value function that you can then reference in the `FROM`. As for the `Case` (`Switch`) statement, T-SQL doesn't support them I'm afraid, only `CASE` expressions. Why are you unable to put the subquery you have in the other statement you have?

Comment: ok. could you rewrite this query so that it will fit into store procedure.

Comment: Could I? No, the Procedure definition you've given isn't complete. Nor do I have sample data or expected results.

Comment: If you want the logic of the subquery in a  sproc, you could simply have that output from a sproc and exec into a temp table.  Perhaps a better solution is to have either a *table value function* or view with that query.  If the *table value function* has params, you would use an APPLY.